# sklearn MLPClassifier - zero hidden layers (i.e. logistic regression)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, mlp

We know that a feed forward neural network with 0 hidden layers (i.e. just an input layer and an output layer) with a sigmoid activation function at the end should be equivalent to logistic regression.

I wish to prove this to be true, but I need to fit 0 hidden layers using the sklearn MLPClassifier module specifically.

My attempt:

```
my_nn = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(0), alpha = 0, 
                        max_iter=10000)
```

but this results in an error message:

`hidden_layer_sizes must be > 0, got [0, 0].`

Is there any way to achieve this using this specific module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like

`my_nn = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(), alpha = 0, max_iter=10000)`